# add a event listener when there is a post request for a specific schema in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, hapi.js

I have two schemas

```
var customerSchema = mongoose.Schema( {
    'joined'     : { 'type' : Date, 'required' : true, 'default' : '01/01/1900' },
    'fname'      : { 'type' : String, 'required' : true, 'default' : '' },
    'lname'      : { 'type' : String, 'required' : true, 'default' : '' },
    'city'       : { 'type' : String, 'required' : true, 'default' : '' },
    'orderTotal' : { 'type' : Number },
    'orders'     : [ { 'type' : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 'ref' : 'orders' } ]
} );

var orderSchema = mongoose.Schema( {
    'product'  : { 'type' : String, 'required' : true },
    'cost'     : { 'type' : Number, 'required' : true },
    'quantity' : { 'type' : Number, 'required' : true },
    'total'    : { 'type' : Number, 'required' : true },
    'customer' : { 'type' : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 'ref' : 'customers' }
} );
```

what I want to do is to add an order and then update the customerSchema orders field. So I did this:

```
exports.addCustomerOrder = function ( request, reply ) {
    var total = request.payload.productQuantity * request.payload.productCost;
    var order = new OrderSchema( {
        'product'  : request.payload.productName,
        'cost'     : request.payload.productCost,
        'quantity' : request.payload.productQuantity,
        'total'    : total
    } ).save( function( err, order ) {
        if ( err ) {
            return reply( {
                'statusCode' : '500',
                'error'      : err,
                'message'    : 'Failed to add order'
            } );
        }
    CustomerSchema.update(  { '_id' : request.params.id },
        { '$push' : { 'orders' : order._id } },
        { 'upsert' : true },
        function( err ) {
            if ( err ) {
                return reply( {
                    'statusCode' : '500',
                    'error'      : err,
                    'message'    : 'Failed to add order'
                } );
            }
            reply( order );
        } );
    } );
};
```

Although it's working, I feel that what I have done here is inefficient. Is there something i'm missing to fully optimize my code? Like adding a event listener for orderSchema for example when I have added a new order it will automatically add the id to the customer rather than chaining two api request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I learned about post hooks! So instead of chaining two queries at the same time, I have this sort of event listener when making a post request with my OrderSchema.

```
OrderSchema.post( 'save', function ( next ) {
    var Customer = Mongoose.model( 'Customer' );

    var conditions = {
        '_id' : this.customerId
    };
    var options = {
        'upsert' : true
    };

    var update = {
        '$push' : {
            'orders' : this._id
        }
    };

    Customer.update( conditions, update, options, function ( err ) {
        if ( err ) {
            throw new Error( err );
        }
    } );
} );
```